# DependencyContext.Default throws error in.net core Test project

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a test project to test .net core WebAPI.  `DependencyContext.Default` in the WebAPI project throws error

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: assembly
```

It's happened in

```
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.DependencyContextLoader.Load(Assembly assembly)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at
```

Could be that test project doesn't have DI resolver as no entry point?

Comment: Can you provide more info about your project? For example: project.json, the test method, what tool are you using for test, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DependencyContext.Default uses Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() to probe for assemblies to load. For the running ASP.NET Core app under Kestrel, it's a console app, so had a valid entry assembly.

In a unit testing environment, where the AppDomain is created and loaded up to run the tests in isolation, the created AppDomain does not have an entry assembly. In order to set the entry assembly, since you don't have access to the AppDomain creation code, you have to use a bit of reflection before building your Startup class:

```
// http://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2015/january/set-entry-assembly-in-unit-testing-methods/
AppDomainManager manager = new AppDomainManager();
FieldInfo entryAssemblyfield = manager.GetType()
    .GetField("m_entryAssembly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
entryAssemblyfield?.SetValue(manager, typeof(Startup).Assembly);

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
FieldInfo domainManagerField = domain.GetType()
    .GetField("_domainManager", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
domainManagerField?.SetValue(domain, manager);
```

Just put this before your unit testing code creates or calls into the Startup class.

Comment: FYI I opened an issue with .NET Core on this https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/1017